# Change an html into a var

Tags: javascript, html

as title i have:

```
var contentString ='< h3 id="demo">< /h3>;
```

i want to change the content of "demo" but don't know how to do it.
any good suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. Is this HTML going to become a new node in the page? Do you have some other plan for this HTML string?

Comment: Ok the idea is to use contentString as content of an infobox, i should take strings from external file and then put them into the html into the var contentString, the html will contain more tags. so i have item="hello"; and i want to put it into "demo" inside contentString

Comment: And just finding the first '>' and inserting the content after it won't do?

Comment: the problem is that contentstring does not contain only that, but a title, 5 paragraph,2 radiobuton, an input and a button, and i need to manipulate every item.

Comment: First, you need to ask about an actual representation of your problem. Second, it seems like you're thinking about the DOM as though it was a string. If it starts off as a string of HTML, fine. But what you ultimately want is to convert your string into DOM nodes, and manipulate the nodes in a manner similar to manipulating any other JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider creating a node instead of creaty an "string node". Just like that:

```
var node = document.createElement('h3');
node.id = 'demo'
node.innerHTML = 'hello';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(node);
```

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/RYHWc/

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid, it should have no spaces between '<' and 'h3'.

```
var contentString ='<h3 id="demo"> text </h3>';
```

After this changing an html's attribute is standard. I've done it in jQuery like this:

```
var contentString ='<h3 id="demo"> text </h3>';
contentString = $(contentString).attr('id', "mynewid");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pee3n/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that way:

```
function changeAttrValue(str,attrName,oldAttrVal,newAttrVal){
    return str.replace(new RegExp(attrName+'="'+oldAttrVal+'"'),attrName+'="'+newAttrVal+'"');
}

changeAttrValue('< h3 id="demo">< /h3>','id','demo','otherId'); // -> '< h3 id="otherId">< /h3>'
changeAttrValue('< h3 class="head">< /h3>','class','head','otherClass'); // -> '< h3 class="otherClass">< /h3>'
```

I'm actually not friend of this notation:

```
new RegExp
```

I recommend you that you use always literals like this:

```
/\w+/, /\d{1,2}/
```

but for the function changeAttrValue I could not find a better solution, sorry...
Nevertheless

p.s. So that the function works, do not write:

```
id='demo'
```

write:

```
id="demo"
```

I hope this helps you and you wanted to accomplish it this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to add content to an element in Javascript from a string.

A simple one is to place a token that you can replace later:

```
var contentString ='<h3 id="demo">__CONTENT__</h3>';
var newContent = 'foo';
contentString = contentString.replace('__CONTENT__', newContent);
```

Or you can have your code divided in multiple vars and concatenate them:

```
var contentString1 = '<h3 id="demo">';
var contentString2 = '</h3>';
var newContent = 'foo';
var contentString = contentString1 + newContent + contentString2;
```

You can also use JQuery, create the DOM element and add the content:

```
var contentString ='<h3 id="demo"></h3>';
var $el = $(contentString);
var newContent = 'foo';
$el.html(newContent);
```

Considering multiple tags in the contentString you can do:

```
var contentString ='<h1>...</h1><h3 id="demo"></h3>';
var newContent = 'foo';

//Create a div wrapper
var $wrapper = $('<div>');

//Add all the content
$wrapper.html(contentString);

//get the element with id "demo"
var $el = $wrapper.find("#demo");

//add content to that element
$el.html(newContent);

//get a string once again with the new content
contentString = $wrapper.html();
```